# Is a left and right simple ring with unity a division ring?

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, division-ring

By a left simple ring I mean a ring with no proper, nontrivial left ideal. 
$R$ be such a ring.
Let $u(≠0)\in R$. Then $Ru=R$ (since $1u=u≠0$). Now $Ru=${$ru:r\in R$}. So there is an $r\in R$ such that $ru=1$.

Right simplicity of $R$ implies that there is an $s\in R$ such that $us=1$. $(ru)s=r(us) \implies 1s=r1 \implies s=r=u^{-1}.$

So each nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. Thus $R$ is a division ring.

Is the claim and/or proof correct?

Comment: So you assume $R$ to be *both* left and right simple? Then yes, it's correct

Comment: But is something wrong with the proof?

Comment: No. But for the 'Similarly' part, right simplicity is needed, which is only mentioned in the title.

Comment: @Berci It's mentioned in the title and therefore when I say "$R$ be such a ring" it means that $R$ is right simple as well.

Comment: Anyway, I edited it.